# Are there known website compatibility issues with Galaxy Nexus phones?

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-browser, galaxy

I'm designing a mobile website but am having some issues with the compatibility.  After testing the website on my Android phone (Rezound) and my brother's iPhone 4, the website looked okay.  But when I asked a friend to test it on his Galaxy Nexus, he says he just gets a black screen.

Are there any known website compatibility issues with the Galaxy Nexus?  The only thing I know about that phone is that it uses Ice Cream Sandwich, but aren't all Android o/s phones going to render the website in a similar, if not identical fashion?

This is the link to the website in question: http://m.studiosimplicit.com.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe the only non-constant thing in the default Android web browser is screen resolution.  Although the hardware may be different, the OS it's running and the software the OS is running are the same.  It should render identically on the same OS.

The only explanation I can come up with is that Ice Cream Sandwich has flaws in its browser.  Though that doesn't seem to make sense either, considering that web page is simple enough.  To be honest, I'm as confused as you are right now...

I'm downloading the SDK to test your website in an emulator.  Let's see what happens.

*Edit: someone else seems to have taken over.  I'll just leave it to him/her.*

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0.2 in the default browser, the latest Opera Mobile and Firefox, and Chrome Beta. All of the aforementioned browsers handled your site fairly well *except* for the default Android browser, which produced the black screen you described on first load, and the menu elements below a large black square on a subsequent load.

If I had to guess, I'd say that this has something to do with the fixed positioning of your `img.bg`. Support for fixed positioning was just recently introduced in Mobile Webkit, and its implementation is still a little rough around the edges. Mobile browsers that don't support `position: fixed` will simply ignore the styling rule and render the element with its inherited positioning while ICS' default browser, which claims to support fixed positioning, will botch the rendering of the element producing the weird behavior we're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out so thoroughly.  I do remember hearing that the Galaxy Nexus had quite a few bugs which was why I opted for the Rezound.  I could take off the position:fixed attribute, but then my background gets kinda screwy-looking.  I basically just took a high res image and used that as my bg image.  My concern is that if I take off the fixed positioning and use a smaller image, it will look wonky on tablets or phones with bigger screens (like the Rezound!).  I'm a novice with jQuery and CSS, but should I look into jQuery solutions or do you have something you could recommend?

Comment: I'd stay away from javascript positioning of your image on mobile devices, as the JS performance of mobile browsers. You may want to see if you can get away with setting your image as the background for an absolutely-positioned div with 100% width and height, and setting its `background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover`. In all honesty, I'm not sure how well the `background-attachment` is supported on mobile devices, but it's certainly worth a shot.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a plugin like iScroll (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to simulate a long scrollable page within an absolutely-positioned div element with a width and height of the viewport, overlaying your absolutely-positioned, equally-sized background image. Yes, this is javascript which may make this suggestion seem like a contradiction to my earlier post, but this plugin has been thoroughly tested and is widely used with minimal adverse effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I revised the background image so that it's displayed as the background image of an absolutely positioned div.  See http://m.studiosimplicit.com/test.html (index page) and http://m.studiosimplicit.com/test2.html (inside page).  It seems to be working on my Rezound with some minor bugs, but how does it look on the Nexus?

Comment: You've got a server error on that page. Let me know when that's out of the way and I'll test it on my GNex.